How to find a file lost after a Windows crash?
I have a computer that was running outlook 2010. It crashed.   Windows looks to be unrestorable - motherboard update that seems to messed up the boot and many attempts to restore system going no where.
The hard drive looks to be intact with no other issues. I have already moved everything to an external drive. However I cannot find my outlook.pst file that has been running on the computer for 10+ years.
I found the archive.pst and I have found another users outlook.pst file. I have done a complete search of the drive for any PST files. It simply isn't there. I have also looked in the common places the PST file would be stored and do not see any large files that could be the PST file.
Given that I have the drive available and that the PST files was probably one of the last things that were used, what are my best options or steps to find this?

PhotoRec or TestDisk may be able to recover the file, but if not: ChkDsk <DriveLetter>: /OfflineScanAndFix. If the .pst was saved on C:, boot to WinRE's command prompt to run ChkDsk so you can see the output and know what's going on:  Shutdown /f /r /o /t 0 → Once booted to WinRE: Advanced → Troubleshoot → Command Prompt. Once recovered, run Outlook's ScanPST.exe against the .pst

Try the trial version of MiniTool Data Recovery. The free version is limited, but might be enough for a single file. Do NOT modify the disk in any way until it's recovered.

R-Studio Undelete: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000 - the best Windows file recovery application. Not only undeletes files, can find files by their internal binary structure.

I'm sorry to hear about your computer crash. Here are some steps you can take to locate your missing Outlook.pst file:

Check the Default Location: The default location of the PST file in Outlook 2010 on a Windows system is usually in one of the following directories:

C:\Users\%username%\Documents\Outlook Files
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook


Use Windows Search: Open Windows Explorer and navigate to the location of the PST file according to your version of Outlook. In the search bar, type *.pst and press Enter. Windows will search for all PST files on your computer and display the results.

Create a New Outlook Profile: If the PST file is still not found, it might be an issue with your Outlook profile. You could try to create a new profile and see if it resolves the issue.

Use a PST File Recovery Software: If the above methods don't work, you might want to consider using a PST file recovery software.


Remember to make sure you have 'Show Hidden Files and Folders' enabled in your Windows settings, as some files may be hidden. Also, please back up any important data before making changes to your system.
I hope this helps!
